# calling $remove from list-controller in MEANJS

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I use a MEANJS Yeoman generator App. In one of my controllers i use this to remove a set of words:

```
// Remove existing wordset
$scope.remove = function() {
  vm.wordset.$remove($state.go('home.wordsetsCreate'));
  $state.go('home.viewPatient', { patientId: $scope.patientId }, { reload: false });
  $scope.hide();
};
```

This works all pretty well, but i need to use the remove function in another controller of the same module (the list controller which shows per default a list of the wordsets). So far im not able to use it there, so i think i need to bring the $remove to a service. But how can i do that?